# delete some part which begins with a url in my sql

Tags: mysql

i have a MySQL table where I want to delete all the entries that contain a part of a string -

for example, in the field "description", a lot of entries might have strings like these:

```
<strong><a href="http://www.example.com/1.html">.....</a></strong>
<strong><a href="http://www.example.com/2.html">.....</a></strong>
<strong><a href="http://www.example.com/3.html">.....</a></strong>
...
```

the table named `test`. how to delete the entries?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM test
    WHERE description LIKE '%some_part_url%'
```

So with your example you could try:

```
DELETE FROM test
    WHERE description LIKE '%http://www.example.com/_.html%'
```

Comment: @enjoylife: did my answer help you? Did you solve your problem?